# ffmpeg: Adding logo to video makes original video time increase

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to add a logo to a video that gradually appears on the middle of the screen but for some reason this adds an extra 2 seconds to the output video, where the video quickly gets stuck. Any idea how to avoid this:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -loop 1 -i "logo.png" ^
-filter_complex "[1]scale=300:-1,hue=s=0,format=rgba[logo];[logo]split[logo1][logo2]; ^
[logo1]colorchannelmixer=aa=0.0[logo1];[logo2]colorchannelmixer=aa=0.2[logo2]; ^
[logo1][logo2]xfade=transition=fade:duration=5:offset=0[logo]; ^
[0][logo]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2" -q:v 0 -shortest -y output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over complicating things. Overlay the logo onto an instance of the video. Then fade this before overlaying onto another instance.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex ^
[0]split[A][B];[A][1]overlay[OL];^
[OL]fade=type=in:start_time=0:duration=5:alpha=1[Top];^
[B][Top]overlay out.mp4
```

Logo can be filtered with scale, hue etc prior to first overlay.

Comment: This does indeed not add the 2 extra seconds, is this because you don't use -loop 1 on the logo? And what does [OL]fade=type=in:start_time=0:duration=5:alpha=1[Top] exactly do does it remove the video from the logo? I'm trying to understand how it works....

Comment: Loop 1 is not necessary when first overlaying to the input. Not sure precisely why 2 seconds are being added in your version because there are several  unnecessary steps that could be an issue. fade=etc, simply fades the overplayed logo/input instance. Applying this to just the logo.png doesn't work because the .png is a still image with no time span, hence it cannot have a start and duration time.

Comment: Thank you very much